# how to switch between collapse and block for 12 different pictures with a single button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is the code I have written but unfortunately it doesn’t work

there are 12 pictures and 2 button. display button and zoom button
when I click on the display button for the first time, if the first picture is invisible it becomes visible and if that’s is visible it becomes invisible. when I click on display button for the second time the same thing happens to picture 2 and this process repeats for all 12 pictures.

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 0;
$( "#dispbtn" ).click(function() {  
var x=("#img"+count) 
if (x.style.display==="collapse") {
    if(count>=12) {
        count = 1;
    } else {
        count++;
    }

$ (x.style.display="block";
});
else {
$ (x.style.display="collapse";
});

});
});
</script>

<style>
.botton {
  height: 30px;
  width: 315px;
}

.table {
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  }
.img {
  display: block;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/blfy.gif" ALT="Butterflies" id="img1" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/eye.gif" ALT="Eye" id="img2" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/wave.gif" ALT="Wave" id="img3" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/jungle.gif" ALT="Jungle" id="img4" class='img' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/bridge.gif" ALT="Bridge" id="img5" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/duck.gif" ALT="Duck" id="img6" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/egg.gif" ALT="Eggs" id="img7" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/aurora.gif" ALT="Aurora" id="img8" class='img' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/it.gif" ALT="Technology" id="img9" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/hill.gif" ALT="Hills" id="img10" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/string.gif" ALT="strings" id="img11" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/vegi.gif" ALT="vegetables" id="img12" class='img' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>

<button class="botton"; id="dispbtn";>Display</button>
<button class="botton"; id="zoombtn";>Zoom</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have several syntax errors in your code (uneven parentheses and so), also where is `dispfunc()` and `zoomfunc()`?

Comment: sorry I had forgotten to delete those functions.

Comment: I was just wondering if you could highlight them or maybe you could fix them for me.
because I'm really new to this language and can't really see where the problems are
so sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish but I think I have an idea. Here's my solution just using vanilla JS, I put some comments in my code too so it kinda walks you through the process of how it works.

```js
(function() {
  // set init count value
  var count = 0;
  // add click event to button
  document.getElementById('display').onclick = function() {
    // grab all the images
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.images');
    // holder for single image
    var image;
    // check if all images are not displayed yet
    if (count < images.length) {
      count++;
    } else {
      // reset counter and hide all images
      count = 1;
      for (var x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {
        image = images[x];
        image.style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
   image = document.getElementById('image-' + count);
   image.style.display = 'block';
 }
})();
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

img.images {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: none;
}

div#display {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">Display</div>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/400/200" class="images" id="image-1" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/500/200" class="images" id="image-2" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/600/200" class="images" id="image-3" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much.
but there is just one problem.
I want images to disappear one by one (just as they appear).
in your example, first click shows first pic, second click shows second pic and third click shows third pic and fourth click makes all 3 pictures disappear.
i want this:
forth pic makes first pic appear and fifth click makes second pic appear and so on

Comment: No problem, I have tutorials on YouTube too; I know you mentioned you're just getting started with JS.

Comment: do you think you can help me with that?

Comment: Okay, try it now.

Comment: it's not what i want yet.
with the fourth click, first picture remains on the screen and second and third pictures disappear at once.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure what you're asking but the base code is there. Shouldn't be hard to tweak it to do what you want it to do!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the syntax errors I commented about, there are a few aspects worth remarking:

1. I personally think there is nothing wrong with mixing vanilla JS with jQuery (although I might get bashed in a few minutes just for saying that) but only (no offense) if you know what you are doing. If you do this:

   `var x = $('#img1');`

   `x` will be a jQuery object, not a dom element, on which you cannot do `x.style`, to access the style property like that you must first access the actual dom element inside the jQuery object:

   `x[0].style`
2. In order to show each image one at a time and AFTER hiding them one at a time as well, you need to properly set `count` first and then *get* the corresponding image tag.
3. Don't know if `"collapse"` exists as a proper value for `display` so in my example I use `"none"`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $("#dispbtn").click(function() {
    //set correct count first
    if(count>=12) {
       count = 1;
    } else {
       count++;
    }

    //getting jQuery object with img tag in it
    var x=$("#img"+count);
    
    
    if (x[0].style.display==="none") {
      
      x[0].style.display="block";
    }
    else {
      x[0].style.display="none";
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.botton {
  height: 30px;
  width: 315px;
}

.table {
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  }
.img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/blfy.gif" ALT="Butterflies" id="img1" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/eye.gif" ALT="Eye" id="img2" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/wave.gif" ALT="Wave" id="img3" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/jungle.gif" ALT="Jungle" id="img4" class='img' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/bridge.gif" ALT="Bridge" id="img5" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/duck.gif" ALT="Duck" id="img6" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/egg.gif" ALT="Eggs" id="img7" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/aurora.gif" ALT="Aurora" id="img8" class='img' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/it.gif" ALT="Technology" id="img9" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/hill.gif" ALT="Hills" id="img10" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/string.gif" ALT="strings" id="img11" class='img' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/vegi.gif" ALT="vegetables" id="img12" class='img' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<button class="botton" id="dispbtn">Display</button>
<button class="botton" id="zoombtn">Zoom</button>


</body>

</html>
```